# unexpected token while reading xml to string in JSR223 sampler

Tags: xml, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I'm trying to read a string which has XML and facing an unexpected token issue.

I'm using a JSR223 Sampler in JMeter and trying to read value by using

`request_payload=vars.get("${requestPayload}");`

I have my xml in variable requestPayload= 
    `"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header><wsse:Security "`

I want to read this value in JSR223 Sampler.

The error message:

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   Script4.groovy: 1: unexpected token: http @ line 1, column 54.
>      t("`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ${} syntax in JSR223, Simply

```
  vars.get("requestPayload");
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.!
but what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: @user3878134 only in JSR223/functions as groovy you can use `vars` and you shouldn't mix  ${} syntax because it's loaded differently

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to overcome the error is given below:

```
vars.get("requestPayload");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]